# Error \mathcal allowed only in math mode. ...\raggedright \textbf{\mathcal{$S_{(TX)}$}}}

Tags: errors, mathcal

I have this error `\mathcal` allowed only in math mode

```
...\raggedright \textbf{\mathcal{$S_{(TX)}$}}}
```

When I run my sub file, where the main file is the dissertation file.

```
\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\raggedright \textbf{\mathcal{$S_{(TX)}$}}} 
\hspace{-20ex} \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\raggedright Alternating Current}\par

\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\raggedright \textbf{\mathcal{$S_{(TX)dffgg}$}} } 
\hspace{-20ex}  \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\raggedright Alternating Current Current}\par
```

Comment: (1) You'll generally get better answers if you can present us with a MWE (minimal working example).  In this case, do you still have the same problem with `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \textbf{\mathcal{$S$}} \end{document}`? Then post that instead.  (2) I think it's telling you that you should be in math mode before starting mathcal, so `$\mathcal{S}$`, not `\mathcal{$S$}`.  (3) But you don't want mathcal inside textbf.  That doesn't make sense.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first try would be enclosing the `\mathcal` in the `$ $`, as follows:

```
\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\raggedright \textbf{$\mathcal{S_{(TX)}}$}} 
\hspace{-20ex} \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\raggedright Alternating Current}\par

\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\raggedright \textbf{$\mathcal{S_{(TX)dffgg}}$} } 
\hspace{-20ex}  \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\raggedright Alternating Current Current}\par
```

See if that works.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. To get the chuck of code displayed correctly, you can `edit` your post by selecting the code then pressing `Ctrl`+`K`.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using lots of (rather convoluted-looking) `\parbox` directives, I'd recommend sticking the material into a two-column `tabular` environment, with the first column in math mode by default.

Incidentally, I'm assuming that only the letter `S` should be in the argument of `\mathcal`.

In the following code, I've omitted the `\textbf` directives since it's not clear to me what they're supposed to accomplish.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} L l @{}}
  \mathcal{S}_{(TX)}      & Alternating Current \\
  \mathcal{S}_{(TX)}dffgg & Alternating Current Current
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```